# Mouse buttons won't work while key is pressed

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop, synaptics-touchpad, mouse-buttons

I have an older Lenovo W530 laptop with latest recommended Synaptics driver (19.0.17.115), Windows 10 Pro.

I occasionally play Minecraft on my laptop using the touchpad and mouse buttons. I learned that I needed to disable PalmCheck in order to be able to use the touchpad at the same time as the keyboard. I also disabled tapping after hitting my pet wolf too many times :-D. Everything works great for my (default admin) account.

I set up a separate account for my son to use so he could play Minecraft with his brother without getting into my stuff. Though I have more than quadruple-checked the Synaptics Ultranav settings from my son's account, the left mouse button refuses to operate when a key is pressed. Interestingly, the touchpad itself DOES respond, it's just the left mouse button that insists on waiting until all keys have been released, so it's clearly not related to PalmCheck.

I can reproduce this at the desktop. If I hold down a key that's not in the name of any icon (e.g. "q") and then try to click on a desktop icon, nothing happens on my son's account, but on mine it registers the click.

So in summary:

- Works fine on my original > 4-year-old account that I migrated from W8 years ago;
- Does not work on a separate account I created a couple of months ago.

Any idea where to begin with this one? This smells like a funky setting in the registry for my son's account.

---

Just tried the following, no improvement:

- Reinstall driver
- Create a new account (this new account has the same problem)
- Set my son's account to administrator
- Re-enabling tapping, as well as the trackpoint

  - No left button action works -- not the trackpoint left button, not tapping, not the touchpad's button -- when a key is being pressed!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to set the touchpad sensitivity to "Most Sensitive" in the Windows 10 settings -- not Ultranav.

Guess there's no distinction between a tap click on the touchpad and a dedicated mouse button click.